# How do I use crontab to export and rsync databases in sql format to my computer?

Tags: mysql, shell

**Situation**
I am trying to automate the downloading of my websites' files, emails and databases to my iMac. I am also trying to use rsync so that besides the first download, the rest will just be incremental. I discovered crontab and have finally gotten the right expression to rsync my websites' files, as per follows:

```
30 01 * * * * rsync -azvv -e 'ssh -p MYPORTNUMBER' root@MYIPADDRESS:/var/www/vhosts/ /Users/MYUSERNAME/var/www/vhosts
```

**Question**
How do I automate the downloading of all the databases in my server in SQL format to my iMac, plus do it in incremental style? There are so many solutions out there but they all seem to suggest using shell script, and that shell script has to be stored on the server. Is it possible to store the shell script on my imac then have the crontab to run it? And can someone please help me with the expressions for it?
I have tried creating a .sh file in my imac, then running it in crontab or terminal. But I get this error message "cannot execute binary file".
Or, should I be finding the script to transform the databases into sql format, store it somewhere on the server, then download it to my computer, then delete it off the server?
I have never touched shell script or crontab until now, so I am very scared that some wrong command will screw up the server or delete or modify files unknowingly.

Answer (score 0):

You want a shell script that will dump your MySQL database to a .sql file and then you can rsync that file over. The script will need to live on your server and create the file. Then you can rsync it over to your Mac. Something like this to get you started:

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/mysqldump MyDatabase > mydatabase_backup.sql
```

Of course this just overwrites your backup each time so if you want to get extra credit you can learn how to create variables based on the current date in a shell script and use the date in your backup file name.